# upload file in vertx and convert it into byte array to insert in database

Tags: java, file-upload, httprequest, vert.x

I need to write upload file code using vertx and then save it into PostgreSQL table. but as file is uploaded in multipart and asynchronously I am unable to get byte complete array.  Following is my code

```
public static void uploadLogo(RoutingContext routingContext) {
    HttpServerRequest request = routingContext.request();
    HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
    request.setExpectMultipart(true);
    request.uploadHandler(upload -> {
        upload.handler(chunk -> {
            byte[] fileBytes = chunk.getBytes();
        });
        upload.endHandler(endHandler -> {
            System.out.println("uploaded successfully");
        });
        upload.exceptionHandler(cause -> {
            request.response().setChunked(true).end("Upload failed");
        });
    });
}
```

Here I get byte array in `fileBytes` but only part at a time. I dont understand how to add next byte array to it as it works asynchronously. Is there any way to get byte array of entire file

Answer (score 2):

Hi I am able to extract bytes by using below code :

```
router.post("/upload").handler(ctx->{
            ctx.request().setExpectMultipart(true);

            ctx.request().bodyHandler(buffer->{
                byte[] bytes=buffer.getBytes();

                //transfer bytes to whichever service you want from here
            });

            ctx.response().end();
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Request context has `.fileUploads()` method for that.
See here for the full example: https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/blob/master/web-examples/src/main/java/io/vertx/example/web/upload/Server.java#L42

If you want to access uploaded files:

```
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

    Router router = Router.router(vertx);

    router.post("/upload").handler(ctx -> {
        for (FileUpload fu : ctx.fileUploads()) {
            vertx.fileSystem().readFile(fu.uploadedFileName(), fileHandler -> {
                // Do something with buffer    
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: But FileUpload doesn't have any method to get byte array. it has methods to write a file only

Comment: FileUpload has a name of the uploaded file, which you can use. I added an example for you.

Comment: This seems good @AlexeySoshin but will this suffice for large files of size greater than 2gb

Comment: The reference that you get is `AsyncResult<Buffer>`, and buffer is a type of a reactive stream. So yes, it doesn't read the file into the memory eagerly, if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

to  get the uploaded  files  you have  to  use `fileUploads()` method after you  can get  the byte array.

```
    JsonArray attachments = new JsonArray();
    for (FileUpload f : routingContext.fileUploads()) {
        Buffer fileUploaded = routingContext.vertx().fileSystem().readFileBlocking(f.uploadedFileName());
        attachments.add(new JsonObject().put("body",fileUploaded.getBytes()).put("contentType",f.contentType())
                .put("fileName",f.fileName()));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to build it manually by appending incoming parts in `upload.handler` into Buffer. Once `upload.endHandler` is called the upload process has ended, and you can get the resulting buffer and its byte array.

```
request.uploadHandler(upload -> {
   Buffer cache = null;

   upload.handler(chunk -> {
       if (cache == null) {
         cache = chunk;
       } else {
         cache.appendBuffer(chunk);
       }
    });

    upload.endHandler(end -> {
        byte[] result = cache.get().getBytes();        
    });
});
```